# Изменение переменных в CSS используя javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Есть элемент

```css
.test {
  --var-width: 100px;
  width: var(--var-width);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">текст</div>
```

Как изменить значение переменной `--var-width` с помощью JS (или jquery)?

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
элемент.style.setProperty('--переменная', 'значение');
```

Пример:

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.test');
var rng = document.getElementById('rng');

rng.onchange = rng.oninput = function() {
    test.style.setProperty('--var-width', this.value + 'px');
    test.textContent = this.value;
};
```

```css
.test {
   --var-width: 100px;
   width: var(--var-width);
   background-color: red; /* для наглядности */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">100</div>
Выберите ширину:<br/>
<input type="range" min="10" max="300" value="100" id="rng" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте,через `element.style.width="100px"`,но лучше задайте дополнительный класс,опишите в нем изменения,а через `js` просто переключайте с помощью `elem.classList.toggle`

update.

```
document.querySelector('.test').style.setProperty('--var-width', '200px');
document.querySelector('.test').style.cssText = "--var-width: 200px";
document.querySelector('.test').setAttribute("style", "--var-width: 200px");
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Вопрос про изменение CSS-переменной, а не про изменение стиля элемента

Comment: прекрасный update после правильного ответа andreymal :)